# Bash error : ambiguous redirect while reading file

Tags: bash

Main idea of the script is to look for patterns in a log file and do something if one or more of the patters are listed in the log.

```
flag=No
while read line;
do
  if  [ $line = “^PAT[0-9]” ]; then
   patnum=`awk –f= ‘{print $1}’`
   pattern=`awk –f= ‘{print $2}’`
    res=`grep –c $pattern FILENAME`
    if res > 0; then
      echo "Do something"
      flag=yes
    fi    
  fi
done < $Pattern_File

if [ flag = yes]; then
      sleep 5
      echo "End result"
fi
```

Pattern_File is something like this :

```
  PAT01="String1"
  PAT02="String2"
  PAT03="String50"
```

After everything is set I'm getting ether this error : bash: $Pattern_File: ambiguous redirect or when i set it like that : done < "$Pattern_File" --> error is No such file or directory.

Any ideas here ? :)

Comment: I think your `$Pattern_File` variable is empty, that's why the error, bash reads `done < `and that's it. Try echoing your variable.

Comment: Pattern_File is the name of the file which is placed in the same directory as the script. "while read line" should read directly from the file if I'm not wrong

Comment: Please read my comment again. Don't *assume* the contents of the variable: check it. Or, if the file is actually named Pattern_File, then drop the dollar sign, since it's a string, not a variable... And if this is the case, delete your question as it is only due to a typo, thereby rendering it useless for future readers:)

Comment: Alright , we have movement. When i deleted the $ sign i got this error : 
bash: [: too many arguments --> 2 times at once .  An currently I have 2 patterns in the file. Sorry if i mislead you at the beginning Mr Deak.

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper double-quotes in the `if [  ]`? They different to me in the markup above. All of them should look like the ones at the end, in the `echo` command. And are you sure that `bash` can do pattern matching for you?

Comment: The same goes for the single quotes in the `awk` calls. Those seem to be `‘` rather than `'`.

Comment: @Todoroff You can use bash -x my_code.sh to trace the evaluation of your code, that will help a lot to figure out if variables are not set, etc...

Comment: Please run your code through shellcheck.net. You have several errors (non-ASCII quotation marks, `if res > 0`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you guys, i've worked on that and i think i have working script now.

Comment: @Todoroff glad we could help. So, repeating my earlier comment: delete your question as it is only due to typos, thereby rendering it useless for future readers:)